# Why am I not getting redirected to logoutSuccessUrl?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

This is causing me quite a headache. All I find is how to *disable* the redirect.
I'm trying to do the opposite and can't seem to figure out how!

What I'm trying to achieve is: after a successful logout, redirect the user to another page (be that the login page or a logout success page, whatever).

What happens is: after a successful logout, I stay on the same page, even though I can see the correct response under network the network tab of the developer tools.

Here's what I currently have:

security config:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .csrf(c -> c.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
                .oauth2Login()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logged-out").permitAll()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }
```

controller method:

```java
    @GetMapping("logged-out")
    public ModelAndView loggedOut(ModelMap model) {
        return new ModelAndView("logged-out", model);
    }
```

js script hooked to the button:

```js
let logout = function() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/logout");
    request.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
    request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html");
    request.send();
}
```

the log events after clicking the button:

```
DEBUG 15539 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/logged-out", parameters={}
DEBUG 15539 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.hamargyuri.petprojectjava2021.controller.HomeController#loggedOut(ModelMap)
DEBUG 15539 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html]
DEBUG 15539 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

[and here's what I see in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcXT2.png)

I'm sure there must be some very stupid thing I'm missing here, but I'm at the stage of banging my head to the wall, so I'd appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it seems that it worked perfectly! ;) Unfortunately, your javascript client is dropping the response on the floor. I think you are relying on a redirect from a javascript client which AFAIK doesn't actually trigger your browser to render the page. Instead, you should be producing a meaningful response on the server for your javascript client and building the response handling into the client.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg thanks, I get it now! I had to make the frontend to act upon a successful logout call. Great, it's working now :)

Comment: Yay! Glad I could help. I can rarely help with UI issues these days, but this one I got!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems like my frontend code was at fault, as it's the one that should do something if the logout call was successful.
I know it's very basic, but this is what I've changed in the js:

```js
let goHome = function() {
    window.location.href = "/";
}

let logout = function() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/logout");
    request.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
    request.onload = goHome;
    request.send();
}
```

I also removed the explicit logoutSuccessUrl, the default is fine, all I need a successful response, then the above function will take me "home".